# SIM is always on EDGE in dual sim setup

Tags: internet, device-firmware, 7.0-nougat, dual-sim

I've got a oneplus 2 running CM 14. Build details are as following.

**version** : 14.1-20161213-NIGHTLY-oneplus2

**CM API** : 7

**Baseband version** : MPSS.B0.2.5.c9-00015-M8994FAAAANAZM-1

**Kernel Version** : 3.10.84

I've recently started using a dual sims within the same career. The thing is, SIM2 always gets HSPA+ and SIM1 only gets EDGE. Sometimes if I restart the device, SIM1 gets HSPA but it changes to EDGE in a couple of minutes. I tried switching the SIMs and the same thing happens. Any idea on the issue?

Comment: Is your only source of this, the text/ symbols you get on the status bar  next to the clock ?

Comment: actually, no I checked the connectivity, speed etc and everything was on EDGE speed. Sometimes I couldn't load web pages as well.

Comment: You can't use HSPA on both SIMs, hardware limitation. Whenever one is set to HSPA, to other is automatically set to EDGE and vice versa.